# Browser doesn't renders table element | jsFiddle example

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code makes a cross domain request to fetch the source of a webpage, using James Padolsey's "cross domain mod for jQuery":  https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax;

Then it selects the first table and appends it to a existing div.

But the appended table doesn't get rendered properly. Can anyone take a look at this fiddle and tell me why?

http://jsfiddle.net/6ZgRf/

Comment: Side note, don't use a global variable to communicate the response from one function to another. Pass it as an argument: `stripViewResponse(res.responseText);` and receive it as a parameter `function stripViewResponse(antwort) {...`

Comment: I know that. But your are right, others maybe won't. So thanks for the hint. Here is the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zjy73

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using jQuery.. so you can traverse it by turning it into a jQuery object

```
function stripViewResponse() {
// Select table element
  var fetchedTable = $(antwort).find('table')[0]; // find first table
// append table
  $('#new').append(fetchedTable);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ZgRf/1/

Comment: Awesome! As you can see I'm just getting started. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
function stripViewResponse() {
// Select table element
    var fetchedTable = $(antwort).find('table').eq(0);
// append table
  $('#new').append(fetchedTable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's almost the same as @wirey suggested.